# Optimise-Volume -Analyze output redirection

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation

I'm really struggling with a powershell command called `Optimize-Volume`, with the `-Analyze` and `-Verbose` switches. This produced a lot of text on the console about the current fragmentation state of the disk, but I'm trying to save this to a file.

There's a number of ways to do this, but none of them seem to be working for me. I've tried using the `>` operator to redirect the stream, I've tried using a pipeline to put the output into an Out-File command, I've tried putting the `Out-File` first and then using the `Optimise-Volume` command as a parameter, nothing seems to be working!

Even if the command itself doesn't have any outputs, I'm not sure I understand why directly redirecting the stream to a file wouldn't work. There *must* be a stream, since it's writing to the console!

Any help would be very much appreciated, I'm out of ideas on this one.

Answer (score 0):

`>` only redirects standard output. Verbose is in another stream (4). Specify the streams you want or redirect all using `*> myfile.txt`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection for more information

Comment: Much appreciated, using the *> gives me what I needed. Owe you one! :)